# Finding all common letters in an unknown set of strings

Tags: python

I want to create a function that takes a list of strings as a parameter and that returns only those characters that are common to all strings. I want to do this using the `set` API.

For example:

```
my_words = ["house", "cheese", "helicopter"]

def FindCommonCharacters(my_words):
    xxxx

Output: {"e", "h"}
```

I know how to do this if I know beforehand how many strings I will have in my list. Since that way I can convert each string into a set and then use the `intersection` operation. But I don't know what to do if I don't know the number of strings... Any ideas?

Note: I can't use `map` nor asterisks (*), as I have seen in similar questions.

Comment: Is it a homework question? Why can't you use `map` nor asterisks (*)?

Comment: Hmm... You do have a point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative without using `*` or `map` is the following:

```
from functools import reduce

my_words = ["house", "cheese", "helicopter"]

my_sets = [set(w) for w in my_words]
head, tail = my_sets[0], my_sets[1:]
result = reduce(set.intersection, tail, head)

print(result)
```

The above approach could be consider the functional version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58191962/4001592). Note that [set.intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) is designed for more multiple sets as can be read in the documentation:

> Return a new set with elements common to the set and all others.

So for the sake of completeness I include two examples below:

```
my_words = ["house", "cheese", "helicopter"]
result = set.intersection(*(set(s) for s in my_words))
```

**Output**

```
{'h', 'e'}
```

As commented by @Jab an alternative is to use map:

```
result = set.intersection(*map(set, my_words))
```

Comment: You can use map here too: `set.intersection(*map(set, my_words))` probably more efficient.

Comment: Actually you can use `set(my_words[0]).intersection(*my_words)` too now that I think of it.

Comment: @SpghttCd answer doesn't work for me... I always get `None` as output. Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC perhaps

```
my_words = ["house", "cheese", "helicopter"]

s = set(my_words[0])
for w in my_words[1:]:
    s = s.intersection(w)

# {'e', 'h'}
```

Comment: This doesn't work... for some reason I always get `None`

Comment: Did you copy/paste exactly that code above and the result of `s` is `None`? I have no idea.